# Cannot get location property from an object i get through an api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im getting a task by its `id`, im scanning a barcode i get the id and i get the `data` of the task, but for some reason i cant `setLocation` to `resultData`. Location, when i log `resultData` i get all the data of the task, when i log `resultData.location` i get the location object, but when i want to `setLocation(resultData.location)` i just get an empty object logged - note in use state default `state` is {}, if i just set the default state to nothing it returns undefined in the console.

```
    import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import BarcodeScannerComponent from 'react-webcam-barcode-scanner';
import axios from '../axios';
import { DashboardContext } from '../contexts/dashboardContext';
import toast from './Notify';
import { database } from '../config/firebase';

const BarcodeReader = ({ setActiveTab, onRequestClose }) => {
  const { setTaskSelected, taskSelected } = useContext(DashboardContext);
  const { isAutoAssign } = useSelector((state) => state.tasks);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({});
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState();
  const [driverLoc, setDriverLoc] = useState([]);
  const [closestDriverID, setClosestDriverID] = useState('')


  const { uid } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: uid,
    },
  };


  




useEffect(() => {

  (async() => {
    const ref = await database.ref('users');
    ref
      .orderByChild('userType')
      .equalTo('driver')
      .on('value', (snapshotq) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
        if (snapshotq.val()) {
          setDrivers(snapshotq.exists() && Object.values(snapshotq.val()));
          
        } 
       
      }) 
  }) ()
}, [])
console.log(drivers, "WEEEEE")

console.log(driverLoc,"WEEWFWFW")

useEffect(() => {
  if (drivers !== undefined) {
// {for (let i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++) {

  setDriverLoc(drivers.map((el) => el.lastLocation))
}

}, [drivers])



const distance =  () => {

       
     if (drivers !== null && drivers !== undefined && drivers.length !== 0)
  
    {
      
      
      
     
let lat1 = location?.latitude;
let lon1 = location?.longitude;
let lat2 = driverLoc.map((el) => el.latitude)
let lon2 = driverLoc.map((el) => el.longitude)

    let radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
  let radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
  let theta = lon1-lon2
  let radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
  let dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  if (dist > 1) {
      dist = 1;
  }
  dist = Math.acos(dist)
  dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
  //  if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
  //  if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }

  for (let i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++) 
{
  
  
  if(dist === drivers[i].lastLocation) {

    setClosestDriverID(drivers[i].uid);

  }}


} else {

  toast.error ('Order location is missing')
}


}
      














  const loadTask = async (taskId) => {
    const { data: resultData } = await axios(
      `order/task/get-by-id/${taskId}`,
      config
    );

    setLocation(resultData.location);
    setTaskSelected(resultData);
    
     
  
      
    console.log('TASK DAAATATAA', Object.keys(resultData));
    console.log('SELECTED', taskSelected)
    console.log('LOCATION', location);
    console.log("DATA LOCATION", resultData.location)
    toast.success('Task loaded');
  };

  const autoAssign = async (taskId) => {
    try {
      
  
      try {
        
        const { data: resultData } = await axios.post(`order/auto-assign/`, {
          taskId: +taskId,
          driverUid: closestDriverID,
        }, config );
        toast.success(resultData.message);
      } catch {
        toast.error(
          'This task is outside the geofence region for this driver'
        );
       
        
      } 
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('This task is outside the geofence region for this driver');
      loadTask(taskId);
      distance()
      onRequestClose();
    }
  };

  const handleBarcode = (result) => {
    setActiveTab('Dashboard');
    if (!isAutoAssign) {
       loadTask(result);
      distance();
      onRequestClose();
      return;
    }
    try {
      autoAssign(result);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('This geofence has more than one driver!');
    }
    onRequestClose();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <BarcodeScannerComponent
        width={800}
        // height={20}
        onUpdate={(err, result) => {
          if (result) handleBarcode(result.text);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default BarcodeReader;
```

This is the call and the logs, here is [what i get in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1gq4.png)

Can someone explain what is going on and how do i get `location`? Thanks in advance

**Note:** i also tried with .then but i got the same results

Comment: The log of `location` here won’t reflect the results of setting state until the next tick; setting state is async. Other than that, hard to say without more context.

Comment: i posted the entire component, please take a look now, thanks

Comment: @DaveNewton the log i sent in the screenshot is actually repeated a couple of times when i scan the barcode, and always the location is {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason is the execution of `setState` is **asynchronous**. So when you `console.log` the `state` just after receiving the api response, You can not see the updated `state` immediately. For more detail explanation, you can checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately).

It seems you need the `location` variable in `distance` function only, so just return the `location` in `loadTask` function and pass it to the `distance` function is fine.

```
const handleBarcode = async (result) => {
  setActiveTab('Dashboard');
  if (!isAutoAssign) {
    // Return location in loadTask function
    const {location} = await loadTask(result);
    // Pass it to distance function directly
    distance(location);
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: then perhaps the fault is in my distance function? how would i find the nearest driver to that location? should i raise a new question for that?

Comment: @greardrear I updated the post. Hope it can help you